# Model validation in Login and Registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

my user model looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(254)]
    [Display(Name="Email address")]
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 6)]
    public String Password { get; set; }
```

rest is irrelevant.

I have following problem: when I try to validate Logging in I need to enter an email address, because it's `[Required]` and `ModelState.IsValid` will return `false` if I wont and log in logic will be skipped... I cant remove `[Required]` coz I need it in Registration, but I also want to let users log in with only username. Is there any way of making Email require only at registration? If not what you suggest me to do, remove Require from email?

Log in:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (IsValid(user.Name, user.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Name, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Data is incorrect");
            }
        }
```

and Register:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = new CardContext())
            {
                var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();

                var encrPass = crypto.Compute(user.Password);

                var sysUser = db.Users.Create();

                sysUser.Avatar = null;
                sysUser.Banned = false;
                sysUser.Email = user.Email;
                sysUser.Information = "";
                sysUser.Name = user.Name;
                sysUser.Password = encrPass;
                sysUser.Rank = null;
                sysUser.Salt = crypto.Salt;

                db.Users.Add(sysUser);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Registration data is incorrect.");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using two separate **[View Models](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx)** -

- a View Model for registration that makes Email required
- a View Model for login that does not have the Email Required.

They are View Models that serve two different purposes so although it looks like duplication, I would consider it not to be.

Comment: I will have to copy everything from registration model to login, when user will register. Or use login model for login validation only and registration model for everything else? It sounds a bit strange, having 2 models, with only difference of [Register] attribute.

Comment: The `User` class that you have represents a user within the business layer. I'm suggesting that instead of passing values from the View and binding to an instance of this type, to use two different View Models instead that have the Validation attributes on them and then map the values from the View Models to an instance of `User` when logging in or registering. Unfortunately, the Data Annotation Validation Attributes have no notion of context by default, although you could write a custom attribute for this.